# CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in

Tags: git, conflict, git-pull

I have a server with a remote and whenever I `git pull` I get those stupid ====== and HEAD >>>> things in my files causing my server to not work properly. How can I prevent this every time I want to update my server to be the same as my origin/master?

This is what I did:

```
git pull production master
```

Then I got this:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in
```

When I do a `git status` I get this:

```
Unmerged paths:
(use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    both modified:      photocomp/settings.py
    both modified:      photocomp/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Can you give a repeatable set of steps to reproduce?  You didn't give us much to go on.

Comment: there you go... that's all i did

Comment: You'll probably find the following posting helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git

Comment: see also kdiff3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you modify files locally.

If you want to keep a pristine branch of your remote master, I suggest you pull the remote master in a separate branch, like you seem to do but do any modifications in a separate branch.

Answer (score 20):

But it is not stupid thing :) Git marks conflicts (see [Merge conflicts in Git](http://genomewiki.ucsc.edu/index.php/Resolving_merge_conflicts_in_Git#Git_can_fail_during_the_merge)) by this way. You must be trying to overwrite changes which haven't been pushed.

`<<<<<<<`: Indicates the start of the lines that had a merge conflict.

`=======`: Indicates the break point used for comparison. Breaks up changes that user has committed (above) to changes coming from merge (below) to visually see the differences.

`>>>>>>>`: Indicates the end of the lines that had a merge conflict.

Resolve a conflict by editing the file to manually merge the parts of the file that git had trouble merging. This may mean discarding either your changes or someone else's or doing a mix of the two. You will also need to delete the `<<<<<<<`, `=======`, and `>>>>>>>` in the file.